# sed: '//D' command

Tags: sed

I'm trying to understand

```
$ echo "reverse me" \ 
| sed '/\n/!G;s/\(.\)\(.*\n\)/&\2\1/;//D;s/.//'
em esrever
```

([found here](http://sed.sourceforge.net/sed1line.txt)).
But I can not get the

```
//D
```

command.
While removing the //

```
/\n/!{
G
}
s/\(.\)\(.*\n\)/&\2\1/
D
s/.//
```

it does not work (seems a loop).

I found nothing about the // address on the man page or the sed faq (where it's used sometimes but not explained).

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in this page:
http://www.catonmat.net/blog/sed-one-liners-explained-part-one/

search this line:

```
37. Reverse a line (emulates "rev" Unix command)
```

Comment: Thank you, so `//` match the last regexp. This is exactly what I was looking for. Now I understand.

Answer (score 0):

From the see man page:

> [2addr]D
>   Delete the initial segment of the pattern space through
>   the first newline character and start the next cycle.

Answer (score 0):

You can omit the contents of a pattern in sed and give it as `//`, which means to treat it as the same as the last regex used. By removing it, you change from deleting when a pattern is matched to always deleting.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
echo reverse me | sed '/\n/!G;l;s/\(.\)\(.*\n\)/&\2\1/;l;//D;s/.//'
reverse me\n$
reverse me\neverse me\nr$
everse me\nr$
everse me\nverse me\ner$
verse me\ner$
verse me\nerse me\nver$
erse me\nver$
erse me\nrse me\never$
rse me\never$
rse me\nse me\nrever$
se me\nrever$
se me\ne me\nsrever$
e me\nsrever$
e me\n me\nesrever$
 me\nesrever$
me\nme\n esrever$
me\n esrever$
me\ne\nm esrever$
e\nm esrever$
e\n\nem esrever$
\nem esrever$
\nem esrever$
em esrever
```

I've added a couple of `l` commands before and after the substitution command

The sed command works as follows:

1. For the first time through only, add a newline to the pattern space `/\n/!G`
2. The regexp groups the first character `\(.\)` (AKA `\1`) and then everything upto the first newline `\(.*\n\)` (AKA `\2`) and then substitutes these two groups by the entire match `&` and then `\2\1`.
3. If the previous regexp is true following the substitution `//D` delete upto the first newline i.e. that is delete the previous `&` expression and begin a new cycle but *do not* read a new line. Effectively loops till the regexp fails.
4. Delete the first character i.e. the newline which has worked it's way to the front of the string `s/.//`